# como creo una tabla con atributo auto increment en android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Hola necesito ayuda como realizar para hacer "auto increment" en sección de `CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO`, Al momento de registrar datos me aparezca, 1,2,3,... sucesivamente. porque se supone se coloca "autoincrement después el integer" lo puse pero al momento de ver los datos me aparece id valor 0; se agradece la ayuda

```
public class Utilidades{

    public static final String TABLA_USUARIO="usuario";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID="id";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO="nombreCompleto";
    public static final String CAMPO_CORREO="correo";
    public static final String CAMPO_CONTRASENIA="contrasenia";
    public static final String CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP="contraseniaRep";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO="CREATE TABLE " +
            ""+TABLA_USUARIO+" ("+CAMPO_ID+" " +
            "INTEGER, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CORREO+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CONTRASENIA+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP+" TEXT)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que sea autoincrementable tu campo en SQLite definelo como llave primaria auto incrementable :

```
  campo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

En tu script supongo que lo asignarías al  campo "id" por lo tanto se realizaría de esta forma:

```
public class Utilidades{

    public static final String TABLA_USUARIO="usuario";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID="id";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO="nombreCompleto";
    public static final String CAMPO_CORREO="correo";
    public static final String CAMPO_CONTRASENIA="contrasenia";
    public static final String CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP="contraseniaRep";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO="CREATE TABLE " +
             TABLA_USUARIO+" ("+CAMPO_ID+" " +
            "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CORREO+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CONTRASENIA+" TEXT,"+CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP+" TEXT)";
}
```

Cuando insertes los valores a tu tabla no es necesario actualices el campo "id".

Revisa el ejemplo de este tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm